# Upload files using FTP in Python TCP proxy program

Tags: python, sockets, networking, tcp, proxy

I am following this article -- https://medium.com/@ismailakkila/black-hat-python-a-tcp-proxy-4528f3dd3b37   to see how a tcp proxy works in python.

The program is tested over a public FTP website https://dlptest.com/ftp-test/.

After running the program in one terminal : python proxy.py 127.0.0.1 21 ftp.dlptest.com 21 True

I am not getting how to upload an file to the https://dlptest.com/ftp-test/ client.

While connecting to the localhost --> 127.0.0.1 in another terminal : It is asking for username and password which I dont understand since It is my local machine.

```
C:\Users\darklion\Downloads>FTP
ftp> open 127.0.0.1 21
Connected to darklion.
220-#########################################################
220-Please upload your web files to the public_html directory.
220-Note that letters are case sensitive.
220-#########################################################
220 This is a private system - No anonymous login
200 OK, UTF-8 enabled
User (darklion:(none)):
```